# CSS rgba isn't working with google chrome

Tags: html, css

RGBA option for input element is not working in Chrome (in all other browsers it is ok). What seems to be the problem? Also, it seems that hole input field is not working as it should o.O???

http://jsfiddle.net/8t5kc/1/

Comment: ref: http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba usable in chrome since version 4.0. Your error lies elsewhere, but you might want to strip down your code to only include the relevant parts and post them here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `<input type="search" />` to `<input type="text" />` it seems to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/8t5kc/2/

"WebKit has big time restrictions on what you can change on a search input. I would guess the idea is consistency." - [read more](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/)

Comment: Silly webkit and it's restrictions :D. Thanks for the article :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Note. If RGBA values are not supported by a user agent, they should be treated like unrecognized values per the CSS forward compatibility parsing rules ([CSS21], Chapter 4). RGBA values must not be treated as simply an RGB value with the opacity ignored.

Comment: Without decimal number I cannot opacity.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?